# What is a descriptor in "generatetodescriptor"?

Tags: address, address-generation, output-script-descriptors

I thought it would be like a label as in:

```
getnewaddress "myawesomelabel"
> bcrt11qay7aqw7azkqhpda22vuzxphkccgmcvc9grz8z
```

but then

```
generatetodescriptor 10 "myawesomelabel"
> myawesomelabel is not a valid descriptor function (code -5)
```

So all I believe I know is that a descriptor is not a label?
What is a descriptor?

Answer (score 2):

If it were a label then the parameter would be named `label`.

Descriptor refers to output script descriptors which are described in [this document](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/descriptors.md) as well as BIPs [380](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0380.mediawiki), [381](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0381.mediawiki), [382](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0382.mediawiki), [383](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0383.mediawiki), [384](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0384.mediawiki), [385](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0385.mediawiki), and [386](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0386.mediawiki),